# How do i resolve ip address changes error on Cpanel

Tags: ip, cpanel, ip-address

I've issues connecting to my cpanel as it keeps bringing ip address change. i have tried using other browsers and even vpn but to no avail. I've been battling this issue over a week now. i will be delighted if anyone can help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is caused when a user logs in, and then the IP address that they are accessing cPanel from changes.

This change is detected by a setting named **'Cookie IP Validation'**.

> WHM: Home -> Server Configuration -> [Tweak Settings](https://docs.cpanel.net/whm/server-configuration/tweak-settings/)
>
> Option: Cookie IP validation

[Check This Link](https://docs.cpanel.net/whm/server-configuration/tweak-settings/#security)

> Scroll down for 'Cookie IP Validation' for more information.

In Tweak Settings, by default, this setting is set to 'strict'.

Changing the value to 'loose' should allow you to be connected.

If you still continue to get disconnected from cPanel or WHM, change the value to 'disable' to stop it entirely.